# EF CORE datetime saves with time 0

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

Good morning,
I have imported my DB tables using DB-scaffold. In one table I have a datetime field where I need to add a DateTime.Now object but, when I save the changes to the DB the date saved is right but the time is 00:00:00.000.

Bellow an extract of my model

```
public partial class Vehicle
{
    // Some other properties....
    public DateTime LastImport { get; set; }
}
```

The DB Context

```
public partial class DBContext : DbContext
{
    // Some other properties....
    public virtual DbSet<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
    
    
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Some other model builders.
        modelBuilder.Entity<Vehicles>(entity =>
        {
            // Some other properties
            entity.Property(e => e.LastImport)
                .HasColumnType("datetime")
                .HasColumnName("last_import");

        });

        OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

And of the update method.

```
private static void UpdateVehicle(IEnumerable<ElencoVettureResponse> vehicles, DbContext ctx)
{
    foreach (var vehicle in vehicles)
    {
        var vehicleRecord = new Vehicle()
        {
            // Setting some other properties
            LastImport = DateTime.Now
        };

        ctx.Add(vehicleRecord);
    }

    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

The table CREATE script:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Vehicle](
/* SOME OTHER FIELDS */
[last_import] [datetime] NOT NULL
```

The field in my DB is filled like this:

[image: DB Screenshot.]

I want the fields to have a value something like this: "**2020-11-17 11:30:19.000**"

What do I have to do? Thank you.

Comment: You show the `Vehicle` class but use `Vetture` in your code. Something's not right there.

Comment: Sorry, changed the variable names to post them here but missed that one.

Comment: Add CREATE TABLE statement of your table, probably in database you have Date column and truncation appear at server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var date = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day,
                        now.Hour, now.Minute, now.Second);

 LastImport = date;
```

Comment: There's no reason why this would solve the issue. Why would a less accurate datetime value be stored correctly? Never seen this behavior in EF core + Sql Server. I think OP has modified something in the meantime, maybe unaware of its significance.

Comment: This is working though.. I noticed while debugging that the date property has the time set to 0.

Comment: There really is no way that setting `LastImport = DateTime.Now` will truncate the datatime value, unless there is some forgotten database trigger that looks at the millisecond part.